# Remove parentheses around year in apacite

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I need to remove parentheses around year in bibliography. I am using apacite.

My setup:

```
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}
...
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{literature}
```

Current version:

```
Callenbach, E. (2002). The Gleaners and I
```

Desired version:

```
Callenbach, E. 2002. The Gleaners and I
```

Is there any way to format my citations like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the parentheses by redefining the `\BBOP` and `\BBCP` macros, as described on p. 33 of the `apacite` documentation.  This needs to be done wrapped in `\AtBeginDocument`.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Saussure1995,
    Author = {Ferdinand de Saussure},
    Origyear = {1916},
    Publisher = {Payot},
    Title = {Cours de Linguistique G{\'e}n{\'e}rale},
    Year = {1995}}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}
\AtBeginDocument{
\renewcommand{\BBOP}{}
\renewcommand{\BBCP}{}
}
\begin{document}

\cite{Saussure1995}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]